# redisTemplate could not deserialize a Object which have an Object property correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

Here is the situation：`TargetObj` is the value which will be set in redis.

```java
public class TargetObj implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private Father property;

    public int getId() {..}
    public void setId(int id) {..}
    public String getName() {..}
    public void setName(String name) {..}
    public Father getProperty() {..}
    public void setProperty(Father property) {..}
```

Class `Father`:

```java
public class Father implements Serializable {

    private String fatherName;

    public String getFatherName() {..}
    public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {..}
```

Class `Son`:

```java
public class Son extends Father implements Serializable {
    String sonName;

    public String getSonName() {..}

    public void setSonName(String sonName) {..}
```

Then, I try to store a `TargetObj` instance in redis by redisTemplate like below:

```java
TargetObj to = new TargetObj();
to.setId(1);
to.setName("toname");
Son son = new Son();
son.setFatherName("fatherName");
son.setSonName("sonName");
to.setProperty(son);//the Property type is Father, and I set a son to it
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("test", to);
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Object test = om.convertValue(redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("test"), TargetObj.class);
```

but I get an error:

```sh
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "sonName" (class com.hyc.backend.dao.Father), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "fatherName"])
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.hyc.backend.dao.TargetObj["property"]->com.hyc.backend.dao.Father["sonName"])
```

In summary, I set an `Son` type instance to field named `property` in the `TargetObj` instance, and the static type of the field is `Father`. Then I store `TargetObj` instance in redis. But I could not deserialize the `property` in `TargetObj` to a `Son` type, spring deserialize it to a `FatherType` and throw an Exception.
`RedisConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);

        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(om);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

My springboot version is 2.4.3. Is there anyone know how to solve it? I have been trapped for two days. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see `SonName` variable name starting with capital `S`. This can be a problem. Can you change it to `sonName` and try again ?

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `sonName`, but the exception still occur.@hiren